# Android webview asks for chooser popup

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, webview, android-websettings

I am trying to load the .pdf file in the webview, but it shows below popup

[image]

How to cancel this popup in Android webview. Please help

Comment: I think WebView doesn't support showing a pdf file. You can use some lib for that, something line (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer)

Comment: @Demigod you are right i am using the same, but When i go back from com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer the shown popup is visible . donot know how to cancel the above shown  dialog

Comment: Share more info about your implementation. It looks like your opening pdf viewer from a web view and not overriding an opening of pdf URL which opens this dialog...

Comment: @Demigod  Please find the implementation below

```override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
    view: WebView?,
    url: String
): Boolean {
                Log.e("pdf Page = ", url!!)
               val regIntent = Intent(this@LoginWebViewActivity, PdfViewActivity::class.java)     
           regIntent.putExtra("pdfurl", url)         
    regIntent.putExtra("ViewType", "internet")
                startActivity(regIntent)
               return true
            }
            return true

}```

Comment: The reason might be that there are two different `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` callbacks (with URL as String and with web resource request). Check if you override both.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS?

> This is broadcast when a user action should request a temporary
>   system dialog to dismiss. Some examples of temporary system dialogs
>   are the notification window-shade and the recent tasks dialog.

Example of using:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
context.sendBroadcast(it);
```

I'm not sure if it works for that dialog.